# v2 Navigation.showModal creating new component instance but not actually navigating to it

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm trying to perform the most simple `showModal` animation with react-native-navigation v2 (version 2.8.0) and I cannot get the new screen to pop over the old one. The new component is hitting a log in its `componentDidMount` function but the navigation is not happening.

I've tried copying and pasting the "Working" code from all the tutorials and the docs.

````
// I Registered the component
Navigation.registerComponent('Test', () => TestView)

// I set the root (and it appears as expected)
Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
      stack: {
        children: [{
          component: {
            name: 'Test'
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  })


// Here is the Component I'm trying to call `showModal` from
export default class TestView extends React.Component<any, any> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    Navigation.events().bindComponent(this)
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    console.log('***MOUNT***')
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={ { flex: 1 } } onPress={ this.navigate }>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#c3c3c3' }} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }

  private navigate = () => {
    Navigation.showModal({
      component: {
        name: 'Test',
        options: {
          modalPresentationStyle: OptionsModalPresentationStyle.overFullScreen,
        }
      }
    })
  }

}```

When the navigate function is called, the log in `componentWillMount` hits (again) but nothing else happens and the root component remains on screen. I'm convinced I'm doing something stupid so hopefully a few more sets of eyes will help. Thanks.
````

Comment: Hey! I'm having the same issue. Any solution?

Comment: iOS only, Android is working ok

Comment: Could you find a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was not properly setting the `id` for the incoming stack. This is the current pattern I'm using that works.

```
Navigation.showModal({
        stack: {
            id: screen,
            children: [{
                component: {
                    id: id,
                    name: screen,
                    passProps: props
                }
            }]
        }
    })
```